# Remove Promises that Return Undefined

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, promise

I'm trying to figure out how to filter out promises that are executed via Promise.all and return undefined. I provided an example below.

I know I can filter them out after the "then" but I'm wondering if they can be removed before it gets to that point.

```js
// External Resource Such as Redis
const getDataFromExternalResource = (key) => {
  const data = {
    "a": "{val: 'valA'}",
    "b": "{val: 'valB'}",
    "d": "{val: 'valD'}",
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve((data[key] ? data[key] : undefined))
  })
}

// Look up Keys that may or may not return 'undefined'
const lookups = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

Promise
.all(lookups.map(key => getDataFromExternalResource(key)))
.then(allData => console.log(allData)) // How can I get rid of the undefined values BEFORE it gets here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may insert one more `.then` call to filter the array right after `Promise.all`. There is no other way, you cannot filter right in `Promise.all`.

```js
// External Resource Such as Redis
const getDataFromExternalResource = (key) => {
  const data = {
    "a": "{val: 'valA'}",
    "b": "{val: 'valB'}",
    "d": "{val: 'valD'}",
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve((data[key] ? data[key] : undefined))
  })
}

// Look up Keys that may or may not return 'undefined'
const lookups = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

Promise
.all(lookups.map(key => getDataFromExternalResource(key)))
// <== next line is the inserted one ==>
.then(allData => allData.filter(x => x !== undefined))
.then(allData => console.log(allData)) // How can I get rid of the undefined values BEFORE it gets here?
```

Comment: That's unfortunate since for large datasets it feels like I'm looping through unnecessarily.

Comment: It's true that there is some unnecessary loop and allocation, but if you think of the big O notation, the whole function will be O(n) anyway. *We are not loosing too much with this*